# How to generate a unique ID using the date and time program by C ++? There is no need to use a library such as windows UUID

Tags: c++

I want to write a C++ program that generates a unique ID without the need for a library, and the date must be represented when the ID is generated.

Comment: You may want to use a database like [postgresql](http://postgresql.org/). This requires days of learning (in particular, about SQL and database normalization)

Comment: Should it be possible to restore the date (and time? What resolution?) from the UUID or only use the date as input? Should the UUID only depend on the date or have some random or sequential input for making it more unique? How many bits? Is it security critical that the uuid cannot be broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can use [UuidCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time_t` type for your ID. It is platform independent and part of C++ standard library. No external library required. Associated functions can help you get the time and date associated with your ID. Please check the reference for details.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/

If you need universally unique ID, that is a low level information and you must depend on operating system. For Windows you can use [UUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/rpcdce/ns-rpcdce-uuid) and for Linux [uuid_t](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_generate.3.html).

On Linux you can use [`uuid_time`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_time.3.html) to trace back to date/time of their uuid_t creation if it was generated based on time (`uuid_generate_time`).

I am not sure if such time extraction is possible for Windows based UUID/GUID.